# Docker Django, redis and celery conf

Tags: django, docker, redis, celery

I dont know what part I am missing but celery not conneting to redis when I am running docker-compose up --build
error: **Cannot connect to redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0: Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:**
**6379. Connection refused.**

Here is my file docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
    
  services:
    web:
      build: .
      image: resolution
      depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
        - celery
      command: bash -c "python3 /code/manage.py migrate && python3 /code/manage.py initialsetup && python3 /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
      volumes:
        - .:/code
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      links:
        - db:db
        - redis:redis
        - celery:celery
      restart: always
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        - PGHOST=trust
        - PGPORT=5432
    db:
      image: postgres:latest
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: 'postgres'
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
        POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
        POSTGRES_HOST: 'trust'
    redis:
      image: "redis:alpine"
      ports:
      - "6379:6379"
      restart: on-failure
    celery:
      image: resolution
      command: celery -A mayan worker -l info
      environment:
        - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mayan.settings.production
      volumes:
        - .:/code
      depends_on:
        - db
        - redis
      links:
        - redis:redis
      restart: on-failure
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`celery` and `redis` are running in different containers.

According to the error message that you shared, most likely, your `celery` is trying to connect to `localhost` to reach the `RedisDB`, which is **not** on localhost.

Seach for the celery configuration file that contains the `CELERY_BROKER_URL` and `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` values. Most likely they look like this:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
```

They should look like this, pointing to the redis service name that you defined in your compose file:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379'
```

If you don't have such a config, search directly for the place where the Celery instance is initialized and make sure it looks like this:

```
app = Celery('server', broker='redis://redis:6379/0')
```

Comment: THIS WAS THE ANSWER